# Prevent redrawing of underlayed elements int QtQuick Qml custom control

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I have two custom QML components, inherited from `QDeclarativeItem`.

In constructors of my components I set this options:

```
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents, false);
setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem::ItemCoordinateCache);
```

In my application I have an element of one type above an element of another type. This elements don't share any properties, but when one of them is redrawing, the another is redrawing too.

If I put some standard element above my elements (like a `Text` or `Rectangle`) and change it's properties, it doesn't make my elements redrawn. So I suppose, I've forgot to set some flag in my components.

How to prevent redrawing of one item when another is changing?

I'm using Qt 4.8 and QtQuick 1.1

Answer (score 1):

In any raster-based rendering system, the drawing is done on a backing store buffer. Thus, when anything changes in a `QGraphicsView`, all items that are not fully obscured must be drawn in back-to-front Z order. If *any* visible item changes, then *all* visible items that intersect it must be redrawn.

What you're seeing looks like normal behavior. Unless you provide some code, it's impossible to tell otherwise.

Comment: I know, but if I'm correct, caching must prevent unnecessary redraw.

And it began working with standard elements since I turned on caching (as I've described above). But with my selfmade components caching doesn't work. I suppose, I should notify the framework that redrawing of my element doesn't affect to appearance of any other element.

Comment: Caching doesn't prevent the need for compositing, and that isn't free either.